# How to write a proper dynamic stored procedure with parameters that can run in a .NET Core database migration without a compile error

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-migration

I currently have an issue where I can run my dynamic stored procedure locally in SQL Server Management Studio without issues. My problem mainly starts when I start running my application, once the scripts start getting compiled it breaks.
 
The application stops compiling and complains about:

> Incorrect syntax near begin statement

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE NAME = 'users')
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS [users];
END;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [users] 
    (@Username nvarchar(500),
     @Progress nvarchar(500),
     @StartDate nvarchar(500),
     @EndDate nvarchar(500),
     @DisplayName nvarchar(500),
     @CourseName nvarchar(500),
     @Search nvarchar(500),
     @Sort nvarchar(500),
     @Page int,
     @PageSize int) 
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    SET ANSI_PADDING ON
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
    SET ARITHABORT ON
    SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
    SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT Off
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 
    DECLARE @offsetcount nvarchar(500)
    DECLARE @pagecount nvarchar(500)
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(500)
    DECLARE @SortFilter nvarchar(500)

    SET @offsetcount = convert(nvarchar,(@PageSize * (@Page - 1)))
    SET @pagecount = convert(nvarchar,(@PageSize))


SET @SQL = 'SELECT [u].[Name], [u].[Username],
           SUM(CASE WHEN [c].[Status] = ''Published'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total,
           sum(case when [ec].[UserCourseStatus] = ''In Progress'' AND [c].[Status] = ''Published'' then 1 else 0 end) AS Pending,
           sum(case when [ec].[UserCourseStatus] = ''Completed'' AND [c].[Status] = ''Published'' then 1 else 0 end) AS Completed
           FROM (([db].[UserCourse] As [ec]
           INNER JOIN [db].[User] As [u]
           ON [u].[Id] = [ec].[UserId])
           INNER JOIN [db].[Course] As [c]
           ON [c].[Id] = [ec].[CourseId])
           WHERE ([u].[StatusCode] = 2 OR [u].[StatusCode] IS NULL) AND [c].[Status] = ''Published''';

IF @DisplayName IS NOT NULL AND LEN(@DisplayName) > 0 
   SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND [u].[Name] = ''' + @DisplayName + ''''
IF @Progress IS NOT NULL AND LEN(@Progress) > 0 
   SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND [ec].[UserCoursestatus] = ''' + @Progress + ''''
IF @StartDate IS NOT NULL AND LEN(@StartDate) > 0 
   SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND ([ec].[DateFirstStarted] >= ''' + @StartDate + ''' AND [ec].[DateFirstCompleted] <= ''' + @EndDate + ''')'
IF @CourseName IS NOT NULL AND LEN(@CourseName) > 0 
   SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND [c].[Name] = ''' + @CourseName + ''''
IF @Search IS NOT NULL AND LEN(@Search) > 0 
   SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND ([e].[Name] like ''%' + @Search + '%'' or' + '[e].[Username] like ''%' + @Search + '%'')'

SET @SortFilter = CASE
     @Sort
     WHEN 'UserAsc' THEN '[u].[Name] ASC'
     WHEN 'UserDesc' THEN '[u].[Name] DESC'
     WHEN 'In Progress' THEN '[ec].[UserCourseStatus] DESC'
     WHEN 'Completed' THEN '[ec].[UserCourseStatus] ASC'
     WHEN 'CreatedDesc' THEN '[ec].[DateFirstStarted] DESC, [ec].[DateFirstCompleted] DESC'
     WHEN 'CreatedAsc' THEN '[ec].[DateFirstStarted] ASC, [ec].[DateFirstCompleted] ASC'
     ELSE '[u].[Name] DESC'
  END

SET @SQL = @SQL + ' GROUP BY [u].[Name], [u].[Username]'
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' Order BY ' + @SortFilter

IF @Page IS NOT NULL AND LEN(@Page) > 0 AND @Page != 0 
   SET @SQL = @SQL + ' OFFSET ' + @offsetcount + ' ROWS FETCH NEXT ' + @pagecount + ' ROWS ONLY'
ELSE 
  SET @SQL = @SQL + ' OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY'
  EXEC(@SQL)
END
GO
```

Comment: It's generally advised to not use syntax such as `EXEC (@SQL);`. Such statements cannot be parametrised, which promote bad habits that result in security flaws like SQL injection. If you need to run a statement that is within a variable or literal string then use [`sys.sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql). Then you can easily parametrise the statement if you need to. Your code *is* hugely vulnerable, and needs to be re-written to parametrise, not inject.

Comment: Not certain why you tag "migration" since this appears to be a runtime issue with your application when in service. But you cannot debug what you cannot see. The first step is to determine what values you pass to your procedure. Take those and use SSMS to run the procedure directly. You can alter the procedure temporarily to select the query before execution so you can **see** the query you build. But `@StartDate nvarchar(500),` is likely a big problem - don't pass dates as strings - solve by parameterizing as already suggested.

Comment: This is a poor way to do dynamic querying. See https://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html for a more in-depth treatment of the subject, with alternatives.

Comment: And apparently nvarchar(500) is just a magic datatype for you. You're not thinking about what datatypes you should use and how all those different lengths will affect the building of your query. What do you expect to happen when a very long value is provided for any one of your current parameters? You will overflow the variable you use for the query. Suggest you read erland's post and [kitchen sink example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example)

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the advice regarding that really appreciate it.

Comment: @SMor thanks for the advice and the links. You have give me a lot to think about regarding my query and datatype approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than injecting the actual search values, you need to pass them all through as parameters, via `sp_executesql`. The `ORDER BY` is the only one that *must* be injected.

You should also pick better data types. Also don't bother quoting with `[]` unless you have to, it's much more difficult to read.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [users]
     @Username nvarchar(500),
     @Progress nvarchar(500),
     @StartDate datetime,
     @EndDate datetime,
     @DisplayName nvarchar(500),
     @CourseName nvarchar(500),
     @Search nvarchar(500),
     @Sort nvarchar(500),
     @Page int,
     @PageSize int
AS
 
SET NOCOUNT ON;
 
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @SortFilter nvarchar(max)

SET @SQL = '
SELECT
  [u].[Name],
  [u].[Username],
  SUM(CASE WHEN [c].[Status] = ''Published'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total,
  sum(case when [ec].[UserCourseStatus] = ''In Progress'' AND [c].[Status] = ''Published'' then 1 else 0 end) AS Pending,
  sum(case when [ec].[UserCourseStatus] = ''Completed'' AND [c].[Status] = ''Published'' then 1 else 0 end) AS Completed
FROM [db].[UserCourse] As [ec]
INNER JOIN [db].[User] As [u] ON [u].[Id] = [ec].[UserId]
INNER JOIN [db].[Course] As [c] ON [c].[Id] = [ec].[CourseId]
WHERE ([u].[StatusCode] = 2 OR [u].[StatusCode] IS NULL)
  AND [c].[Status] = ''Published''
';

IF @DisplayName IS NOT NULL AND LEN(@DisplayName) > 0 
   SET @SQL += '  AND [u].[Name] = @DisplayName
';
IF @Progress IS NOT NULL AND LEN(@Progress) > 0 
   SET @SQL += '  AND [ec].[UserCoursestatus] = @Progress
';
IF @StartDate IS NOT NULL
   SET @SQL += '  AND ([ec].[DateFirstStarted] >= @StartDate AND [ec].[DateFirstCompleted] <= @EndDate)
';
IF @CourseName IS NOT NULL AND LEN(@CourseName) > 0 
   SET @SQL += '  AND [c].[Name] = @CourseName
';
IF @Search IS NOT NULL AND LEN(@Search) > 0 
   SET @SQL += '  AND ([e].[Name] like ''%'' + @Search + ''%'' or [e].[Username] like ''%'' + @Search + ''%'')
';

SET @SQL += 'GROUP BY [u].[Name], [u].[Username]
';

SET @SortFilter = CASE
     @Sort
     WHEN 'UserAsc' THEN '[u].[Name] ASC'
     WHEN 'UserDesc' THEN '[u].[Name] DESC'
     WHEN 'In Progress' THEN '[ec].[UserCourseStatus] DESC'
     WHEN 'Completed' THEN '[ec].[UserCourseStatus] ASC'
     WHEN 'CreatedDesc' THEN '[ec].[DateFirstStarted] DESC, [ec].[DateFirstCompleted] DESC'
     WHEN 'CreatedAsc' THEN '[ec].[DateFirstStarted] ASC, [ec].[DateFirstCompleted] ASC'
     ELSE '[u].[Name] DESC'
  END;

SET @SQL += ' Order BY ' + @SortFilter + '
';

IF @Page IS NOT NULL AND @Page <> 0 
   SET @SQL += ' OFFSET @PageSize * (@Page - 1) ROWS FETCH NEXT @pagecount  ROWS ONLY';
ELSE 
  SET @SQL = @SQL + ' OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY';
END;

EXEC sp_executesql
    @SQL,
  N'
     @Username nvarchar(500),
     @Progress nvarchar(500),
     @StartDate datetime,
     @EndDate datetime,
     @DisplayName nvarchar(500),
     @CourseName nvarchar(500),
     @Search nvarchar(500),
     @Page int,
     @PageSize int
  ',
     @Username = @Username,
     @Progress = @Progress,
     @StartDate = @StartDate,
     @EndDate = @EndDate,
     @DisplayName = @DisplayName,
     @CourseName = @CourseName,
     @Search = @Search,
     @Sort = @Sort,
     @Page = @Page,
     @PageSize = @PageSize;
```